# Entering data from one Worksheet into a specific cell on a specific line of a different worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy The value from a formula in cell R15 on sheet3 into a specific cell on a specific line on Sheet6. The specific line is determined by the data entered into cell O15 on sheet3 matching the data on the specific line on sheet6. I have managed to work out how to locate the correct line on sheet6 with the following code
`Sheets("Sheet6").Range("C310").Value = WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Sheet3").Range("O15").Value, Sheets("sheet3").Range("C1:C300"), 0)`

The code above returns the correct line number in cell C310, I just haven't worked out how to use this information to be able to copy the data from Cell R15 onto a cell along the row shown by the result of the above code in C310 above.

I have tried searching online, but I think I am probably typing the wrong question to return the answer I am looking for.

Could someone please point me in the right direction, so I can get the information copied over to the correct cell, once the matching process has been performed.

Comment: In which cell exactly do you want R15 to be pasted?

Comment: Also you need just the value that the formula evaluates, or the formula too?

Comment: `Sheets("Sheet6").cells(lineNumberYouFound, columnNumberOfCell).value = sheets("Sheet3").cells(15,18).value` (cells(15,18) = range(R15). Is this what you looking for? Your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: Like I said, I am struggling with trying to come up with a clear way of explaining what I am trying to do! Currently I am trying to use the information generated in C310 which identifies the correct line in Sheet 6, so I can copy the result of a formula in R15 on sheet 3 into the correct cell in column L. So if C310 comes up with line 133 then that data should be place in L133. Hope this clarifies it a bit better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this line of code after these you posted:

```
Sheets("Sheet6").Cells(Sheets("Sheet6").Range("C310"), i) = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("R15")
```

and replace i with the corresponding number of the desired column. (eg. 5 is for column E)

Comment: Thank you for this code, which I have tried. Unfortunately it doesn't want to work! I wrote the code like this ```Sub CopyData()

Sheets("Sheet6").Range("C310").Value = WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Sheet3").Range("O15").Value, Sheets("Sheet6").Range("C1:C300"), 0)
Sheets("Sheet6").Cells(Sheets("Sheet6").Range("C130"), 12) = Sheets

End Sub``` but I now get Run Time Error "1004": Application defined or object defined error.

Comment: Before `End Sub` you wrote `= Sheets` . This is not correct. Replace it with  `= Sheets("Sheet3").Range("R15")`

Comment: Hi @dimitris I have adjusted the code so it reads as follows ```Sub CopyData()
 Sheets("Sheet6").Range("C310").Value = WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Sheet3").Range("O15").Value, Sheets("Sheet6").Range("C1:C300"), 0)
 Sheets("Sheet6").Cells(Sheets("Sheet6").Range("C130"), i) = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("R15")
     
End Sub``` It is still coming up with the same Run Time Error "1004"

Comment: Excuse me I wrote 130 instead of 310. I 'm updating the answer. Tell me if it works.

Comment: I've changed the C130 to C310, and yet I am still receiving the same 1004 Run Time Error. Is there some code I have missed?

Comment: That's strange. This one works for me. Can you post once again the whole block of code to see if something is wrong?

Comment: Check out which exactly is the value of C310 before the error. Add this before the line with the error: `Debug.Print Sheets("Sheet6").Range("C310") `

Comment: Check C310's value when the code runs. Seems like it isn't a number.

Comment: use the code you write in the 3rd comment (Sep 13 at 11:18) BUT **replace** the **'i' with the number of the column** as I told you in the answer.

Comment: Hi @dimitris, I have been tinkering about with the code and have now got as far as this ```Sub CopyData2() Dim FTW As Long Dim myVariable As String myVariable = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("R15").Value MsgBox (myVariable) Sheets("Sheet6").Range("C310").Value = WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Sheet3").Range("O15").Value, Sheets("Sheet6").Range("C1:C300"), 0) FTW = Sheets("Sheet6").Range("C310").Value MsgBox (FTW) End Sub``` I have put MsgBox in to see if everything is working, so far, it works fine. What I now want to do is have some code that goes along the line of L:(FTW) = MyVariable

Comment: I tried changing the letter "i" to 12 (it should be Column L?). I am still getting the same Run time error code as before. Maybe the comment I made above might prove more productive in resolving the issue I seem to have?

Comment: what to you want to do with `L:(FTW) = MyVariable` ? tell me this and I will help you with the syntax.

Comment: What I am trying to do, is place the result of myVariable into the cell in column L determined by the result of FTW. FTW is a unique number pulled from O15 on sheet3 and matches the same number in column C on sheet6. So FTW becomes the line number. myVariable is a date that is copied from R15 on sheet3 and placed in column L, line FTW. I hope that make sense to you?

Comment: this is crystal clear now! thank you. I think you need to add this line and you 're done `Sheets("Sheet6").Cells(FTW, 12) = myVariable`

Comment: Thank You @dimitris, that last piece of code has solved the whole problem! I just had to change MyVariable to Long instead of String and everything works a treat!

Comment: You are welcome. I was sure we can solve this one. Good day to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
x = WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Sheet3").Range("O15").Value,Sheets("sheet3").Range("C1:C300"), 0)

Sheets("Sheet3").Range("D" & x).Value = x
```

replace Sheets("Sheet3").Range("D" & x) with desired sheet and range

Comment: Hi gaby. thank you for your answer. Could you please expand on your answer a bit please? You have used Range("D" & x) in your code, does the D refer to the range I have in sheet6 of C1 to C300, and the x refers to the result generated in cell C310?